# How to insert PHP statement in Script

Tags: php, jquery, drop-down-menu, append, removechild

I've seen many people saying that it's not possible to insert PHP statements within a Script, but is there any other way that I could go about doing it?

I've found a Jquery(?) script online that allows me to append and remove textbox.
**Here's part of the code:**

```
<script>
    $(`.buttons`).append (`<input type="text" name="txt"> <input type="button" class="btnRemove" value="Remove"><br>`); // end append  
</script>
```

However, instead of using textbox, I want to use drop down list `<select>...</select>` by populating from the database. With that said, I need to use `<?php (Retrieve stuffs from database and populate here) ?>`

I tried putting the php tags within the script tags, but nothing happens. How else can I go about doing it?

---

Here's my codes. Oh man, i really have no idea how to make my codes be in the gray box. I have already declared allFEArray in codes. (Sorry for my terrible indentations, i'm still new to this)

```
<script>            
    $(document).ready (function () {                
        $('.btnAdd').click (function () {                                        
            $('.buttons').append (   
                            <?php               
            $userCtrl = new user_controller();
            $allFEArray = $userCtrl->retrieveAllFE(); 
                            if($allFEArray != null) { //if there are field engineers
                              echo 'Name: <select name="fieldEngineers[]" style="width: 180px;">';
                                foreach ($allFEArray as $fe) {
                                  echo "<option value =".$fe.">".$fe."</option>";
                                }//end for each
                              echo '</select>';
              echo ' <input type="button" class="btnRemove" value="Remove"><br>';
                            }
                            ?>

            ); // end append                            
            $('.btnRemove').on('click', function () { 
                $(this).prev().remove (); // remove the textbox
                $(this).next ().remove (); // remove the <br>
                $(this).remove (); // remove the button
            });
        }); // end click                                            
    }); // end ready        
</script>
```

Comment: You need to either populate the `select` element with data from your DB on the server-side, or you can do it client side using AJAX.

Comment: What is wrong with `<select><?PHP loop over db here ?></select>`? If you need to do it dynamically, search for PHP and AJAX

Comment: Beware! The back tick ` (not to be confused for ') will cause your code to fail.

Comment: @mplungjan Hi, the <?php ?> tag does not work within <script> tags. Nothing was loading.

Comment: @user3622571 maybe show us the `<?php ... ?>` that wasn't working. then we can help.

Comment: @user3558931 My code initially was '<bla bla bla>', but apparently it wasn't showing up on the display, and when i did the back tick, my codes displayed. So I just used it haha. Whichever works =\

Comment: I meant: Why not just use PHP and HTML and NOT script. If you format the php it DOES work inside script, but will be executed when the php renders, not when the script function is called. You many NOT have newlines in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want the function to access the database when clicked, you need to do this:

```
<script>            
$(document).ready (function () {                
  $('.btnAdd').click (function () {
    $('.buttons').append (   
      <?php               
       $userCtrl = new user_controller();
       $allFEArray = $userCtrl->retrieveAllFE(); 
       if($allFEArray != null) { //if there are field engineers

         echo '\'Name: <select name="fieldEngineers[]" style="width: 180px;">\'+';
         foreach ($allFEArray as $fe) { 
           echo '\'<option value =".$fe.">".$fe."</option>"\'+';
         }//end for each
         echo "'</select>'+";
         echo '\'<input type="button" class="btnRemove" value="Remove"><br>\'';
       } ?>
     ); // end append                            
     $('.btnRemove').on('click', function () { 
       $(this).prev().remove (); // remove the textbox
       $(this).next ().remove (); // remove the <br>
       $(this).remove (); // remove the button
     });
  }); // end click    
}); // end ready        
</script>
```

Comment: what was being changed?

Comment: Quotes and concatenation